# Multivariable Calculus Changing the order of Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6co5.png)

$\int_0^2 \int_0^{4-x^2} \int_0^{4-y} \, dz \, dy \, dx$

Change the limits of integration to match the specified order below.

$\int_a^b \int_c^d \int_e^f \, dx \, dy \, dz$

I did the work and got an answer of

$a=0, b=4, c=0, d = 4-z, e= -\sqrt{4-y}, f = \sqrt{4-y}$.

However my $e$ is incorrect, wonder what I did wrong / what's the right answer.

Comment: Also pls type in your question instead of an image

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the first integral that $0 \leq x \leq 2$ so lower bound of $x$ in your second integral is incorrect.

Your integral should be $\displaystyle \int_0^4 \int_0^{4-z} \int_0^{\sqrt{4-y}} \, dx \, dy \, dz$.